# Microk8s cannot pull from private registry

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microk8s

I'm running Microk8s on an EC2 instance. I fail to pull containers from our private registry. When trying to run such a container `kubectl describe pod` shows:

> Failed to pull image "docker.xxx.com/import:v1": rpc
>   error: code = Unknown desc = failed to resolve image
>   "docker.xxx.com/import:v1": no available registry
>   endpoint: failed to fetch anonymous token: unexpected status: 401
>   Unauthorized

I can `docker login` and `docker pull` from that machine. The yaml I used to deploy the container is working fine on another (non containerd) cluster. It refers to a pull secret, which is identical to the one used in the other cluster and working fine there.

I added the following entry to the containerd-template.toml of Microk8s:

```
   [plugins.cri.registry]
      [plugins.cri.registry.mirrors]
        ...
        [plugins.cri.registry.mirrors."docker.xxx.com"]
          endpoint = ["https://docker.xxx.com"]
```

I have no idea what else I might be missing.

Comment: Did you enable registry? `microk8s.enable registry` Did you edit deamon.json? `sudo vim /etc/docker/daemon.json` with entry like `{
  "insecure-registries" : ["yourRepository"]
}'

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting an error `401` probably something is wrong with the authentication. E.g. you are missing credentials to your private registry.

To make sure that microk8s would use proper credentials, in addition of `mirrors` sections within the configuration you have to specify `auths` section where you would put your docker registry credentials.

```
[plugins.cri.registry.auths]
  [plugins.cri.registry.auths."https://gcr.io"]
    username = ""
    password = ""
    auth = ""
    identitytoken = ""
```

Attributes within that section are compatible with configuration which you can find in your `.docker/config.json`.

Notice that this is section on the same level as `mirrors` it should not be part of `mirrors` entry but added as new section. 
Another important part is to make sure that the `auth` hosts match yours registry host (e.g. https vs http).

For more details check reference: https://github.com/containerd/cri/blob/master/docs/registry.md

p.s. Keep in mind that `containerd` is supported from microk8s[1] `v1.14` if you use older version you should check other options like official kubernates documentation[2]

[1] https://microk8s.io/docs/working

[2] https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to:

1) create a `secret` in the current namespace:

```
k create secret docker-registry my-private-registry \
  --docker-server=my-private-registry.io \
  --docker-username="my-username" \
  --docker-password="********" \
  --docker-email=my.email@helloworld.io
```

2) patch the `default` service account:

```
k patch serviceaccount default -p '{"imagePullSecrets": [{"name": "my-private-registry"}]}'
```

After this you can reference images from your private docker registry in your pod/deployment/replicaset definitions. Perform the same sequence for every namespace you'll be using.

HTH.